# Switching back to iOS12.3 from iOS 13 beta 3

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, backup, restore

I want to switch back to iOS12.3 from iOS 13.

For this apple support says that It can be done by restoring backup [from iTunes:](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/restore#ios)

But iTunes is not installed on my Ubuntu computer. so How to switch back to original iOS from iCloud backup?

One crude way I understand, is to format iPhone and this will turn phone into new one, then I can restore the backup from iCloud. Will formatting the iPhone restore the iOS 12.3 ?

Edit: I erased everything, and restarted as new iphone/also restored from very old icloud backup. But phone didn't switch back to iOS12.3.

Comment: You have run an iCloud backup *after* upgrading to iOS 13?

Comment: @nohillside, Not sure, I will have to check, but most probably it has been back up after iOS13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have ran a backup using iCloud while on iOS 13, and you don't have iTunes, there is unfortunately nothing you can do. If you have iTunes, you could restore from an old backup if you have one, or you can set up as a brand new phone on iOS 12.3 if you download the [.ipsw fil](https://ipsw.me/12.3)e for your phone model and correct iOS.

Comment: Yes I have ran a backup using iOS13, but after resetting, and  restored from an old back up (iOS 12.3), but it didn't remove iOS13.

Comment: How did you do a reset? Just `Erase Contents & Settings`? I would recommend trying a Recovery Mode Restore. Documentation on how to do that is here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201263

Comment: Yes, using `Erase Contents & Settings`, In attached link of yours, it says to use iTunes!, and i dont have iTunes. Anyway, I waiting August to pass and stable release to come in september.

Comment: Just using `Erase Contents & Settings` does just that - erases the contents and device settings. It unfortunately does not erase the current operating system. In order to do that, you will need to use iTunes. You can either install it to your operating system (https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-use-itunes-on-linux-1999251), or take it to an Apple Store or AASP (Apple Authorized Service Provider), and they will be able to do it too.

Comment: Thanks for writing, Yes, I have done it using itunes.

Comment: Did that resolve it?

Comment: Yes! It resolved